# code first, Is it possible to generate a script between two migration?

Tags: entity-framework-migrations

I have three migrations.

201510161138216_InitialCreate

201604251441212_CompanyChanges

201607011420162_AddDeniedDomainRole

From my localhost, the migration has been run and the database is upto the latest version.

I am wondering if I can generate a script now betwwen two migration, so I will have a script that can apply to live servers (don't really trust auto database change on live).
I tried this:

```
Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration: $CompanyChanges -TargetMigration: $AddDeniedDomainRole
```

However, it comes back saying No pending explicit migrations. So is it still possible to create a script?

Comment: turned out Microsoft changed syntax now, it is Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration: CompanyChanges -TargetMigration: AddDeniedDomainRole